# Can't get label text to update swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, uilabel, segue

There is a label on my `ProductViewController` called *idLabel* that I am trying to update. Here is the `VC` that sends the info. At one point I had the text updating when you press the *playThis* button and the label would change from the stock label text to nothing so I know something is happening but now that it is in the `viewDidLoad` it just shows nothing. How do I make it show the text on my receiving end?

here is the sending VC:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseDatabase
import FirebaseStorage

class ListViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableViewProducts: UITableView!

    var delegate: ListViewController?

    var ref:DatabaseReference?
    var databaseHandle: DatabaseHandle?

    var postData = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        ref = Database.database().reference()

        databaseHandle = ref?.child("0").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapShot) in

            let post = snapShot.value as? String
            if let actualPost = post {

                self.postData.append(actualPost)

                self.tableViewProducts.reloadData()

            }
        })
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        print(postData)
        return postData.count

    }

    //This places the text on the ViewControllerTableViewCell which does show up

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")
        cell?.textLabel?.text = postData[indexPath.row]

        cell?.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.white

        return cell!
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        performSegue(withIdentifier: "showDetails", sender: self)
    }

    //This code is what sends the text data elswhere
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let destination = segue.destination as? ProductViewController {
            destination.updater?.id = postData[(tableViewProducts.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row)!]
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the `ProductViewController`:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import Firebase

class ProductViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var idLabel: UILabel!

    var passStuff: productsList?

    var updater: productsList?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        idLabel.text = updater?.id
    }

    var player : AVPlayer!

    let url = "http://listen.shoutcast.com/radiodeltalebanon"

    @IBAction func playThis(_ sender: Any) {

        print("Something is playing")
    }
    @IBAction func pauseBtn(_ sender: Any) {
        player.pause()
    }
}
```

Comment: `updater` is never being set.

Comment: Move *idLabel.text = updater?.id* to viewWillAppear().

Answer (score 0):

If you just planning to pass the id instead of an object then use a simple variable.

Your code in prepare for segue then becomes

```
destination.variable = id_to_pass.
```

Now you got the id in the ProductViewController you can update it in viewdidload

Answer (score -1):

> Problem in the setting value of `updater` from ListViewController

You are setting the value to a object which is not been initialised yet.

```
//This code is what sends the text data elswhere
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let destination = segue.destination as? ProductViewController {
        destination.updater?.id = postData[(tableViewProducts.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row)!]
    }
}
```

Update the code in the following way

```
//This code is what sends the text data elswhere
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let destination = segue.destination as? ProductViewController,
        let index = tableViewProducts.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row {

        // Check whether postData array count is greater than index
        let updaterId = postData.count > index ? postData[index] : ""

        // Initialize "productsList" instance and assign the id value and sent this object to next view controller
        var updater = productsList()
        updater.id = updaterId
        destination.updater = updater
    }
}
```

Comment: OK so i updated the code but when I add in my parameters to initialize productsList I get an error: Cannot convert value of type 'String?.Type' to expected argument type 'String?'

Comment: @pillarman38 , first of all you shouldn't take property name as `id`/ `description`..etc, as this are the default properties and apple denies to use it rather you can take name as `updaterId`. Second,  what is the type of your `id` property in `updater` modal? Is it enum of `String` type? if yes, share the enum as well.